# Oracle extractValue Function not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract values from an XML Column in oracle. My Query is below:

```
select extractValue(COLUMN_NAME, '/parent/element1/')
from   TABLE_NAME where id = 111111;
```

However, I get the below error in my SQL Developer:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Additional info:

1. The columnn type I am trying to query is: VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
2. The XML Contents in the column are very simple, a snippet is below:

> ```
> <parent>
>    <element1>value</element1>
>    <element2>value</element2>
>    <element3>value</element3>
> </parent>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ExtractValue` function can only be called on an XML data type. Try using the `XMLTYPE` function to convert your VARCHAR2 to an XML type:

```
select extractValue(XMLTYPE(COLUMN_NAME), '/parent/element1/')
from   TABLE_NAME where id = 111111;
```